# is there other way to compute the Time with Am and Pm Correctly?

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

I have a time 17:00:00 which is 5:00 PM and I subtract it into 12:00 Pm and the out put is always 5 which is wrong it should be 7 .

$overtime = round((abs(strtotime('17:00:00') - strtotime('12:00')) / 60) / 60, 2);

Comment: is anything wrong with 5? You will of cause get 5 since you will get 300 minutes which is 5 hour?

Comment: `17 - 12 = 5` no?  How does that `output is always 5 which is wrong it should be 7` - work...

Comment: i mean 17:00 is = 5:00 pm  and i subtract it to 12:00 pm it should be 7 hrs of work

Comment: the equivalent of  17:00:00  is equals to 05:00 pm  and the equivalent for 5:00 am is 05:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are confusing 12:00 PM (noon) with 12:00 am (midnight). 17:00 is 7 hours away from midnight (12:00 AM or 24:00 (today) or 00:00 (tomorrow)).

According to [24-hour clock - Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#section_1):

> **Midnight 00:00 and 24:00**
>
> In the 24-hour time notation, the day begins at midnight, 00:00, and
>   the last minute of the day begins at 23:59. Where convenient, the
>   notation 24:00 may also be used to refer to midnight at the end of a
>   given date[5] – that is, 24:00 of one day is the same time as 00:00 of
>   the following day.

You want to subtract `strtotime('24:00')`